# How to get access token for GoToWebinar using Classic ASP and Strict OAuth 2.0

Tags: vbscript, oauth-2.0, asp-classic, access-token

We are currently using GoToWebinars API to create webinars and registrants via the legacy OAuth method.

We are late in the game to change over to Strict OAuth 2.0 and need some guidance on how to quickly change over to the new method.

We have a web application written in classic ASP which requests the access token and then creates webinars and registrants.

Can you provide some code examples on how we can move to Strict OAuth 2.0?

Here is an example of our current ASP code to create tokens using the legacy method:

```
 Function getAccessToken()
   postURL = "https://api.getgo.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=password&user_id={userId}&password={password}&client_id=" & client_id

   Set ServerXmlHttp = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
   ServerXmlHttp.open "POST", postURL
   ServerXmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
   ServerXmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Length", Len(PostData)
   ServerXmlHttp.send PostData

   jsonResponse = ServerXmlHttp.responseText

   'Get Access Token
   set myJson = JSON.parse(jsonResponse)
   access_token = myJson.access_token

   getAccessToken = access_token

   Set ServerXmlHttp = Nothing
End Function
```

I have limited knowledge around strict OAuth 2.0 and can't get my head around creating access tokens programmatically.

Comment: Have you checked out https://www.example-code.com/asp/oauth2.asp ? I have played around with getting oAuth2 working with classic ASP alone and never had any luck...

Comment: Thanks Ralpharama. I have now solved this issue, will post the working code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the following ASP classic code it worked with OAuth 2.0.

```
<script language="javascript" runat="server" src="/global/json2.min.asp"></script>

Function getCitrixAccessToken()

postURL = "https://api.getgo.com/oauth/v2/token"
postData = "grant_type=password&username={username}&password={password}"

Set ServerXmlHttp = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
ServerXmlHttp.open "POST", postURL
ServerXmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
ServerXmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " & encodedAuthHeader
ServerXmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Length", Len(PostData)
ServerXmlHttp.send PostData

jsonResponse = ServerXmlHttp.responseText

'Get Access Token
set myJson = JSON.parse(jsonResponse)
access_token = myJson.access_token

getCitrixAccessToken = access_token

Set ServerXmlHttp = Nothing

End Function
```

Hope this will help someone else with the same issue.

Comment: Do you have a copy of the json2.min.asp? I have been trying to achieve what you have done but can't find that file anywhere on the internet. Be great if you can share a link to it or where you go t it from. Thank you.

Comment: @scw you should be able to find json2.asp that is the same file just not minified, but helps as you can see the code it has written in clearview [JSON2.ASP](https://github.com/nagaozen/asp-xtreme-evolution/raw/master/lib/axe/classes/Parsers/json2.asp)
[JSON2.MIN.ASP](https://github.com/snipertulip/ASPCMS/raw/master/inc/JavaScript/Class/json2.min.asp)

Comment: I can provide it if you need it via email?